# Can somebody give a snippet of "append if not exists" method in swift array?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, append

Because I use this routine a lot, can somebody create an extension method of Swift array which will detect whether if the data that is going to be appended already exists, then it's not appended? I know that it's only a matter of few code like this:

```
var arr = [Int]()
for element in inputArr {
    if !arr.contains(element) { arr.append(element); }
}
```

Becomes:

```
var arr = [Int]()
for element in inputArr { arr.appendUnique(element); }
```

Or:

```
var arr = [String]()
for element in inputArr {
    if !arr.contains(element) { arr.append(element); }
}
```

Becomes:

```
var arr = [String]()
for element in inputArr { arr.appendUnique(element); }
```

Same method for different element types. Frankly, from this simple code, I also want to learn on how to extend the `Collection` with variable types. It fascinates me how Array's methods can have different parameter types whenever the object was initialized with different parameter types. Array and Dictionary are two things that I still don't get how to extend them properly. Thanks.

Comment: why not use Set instead?

Comment: A set has no order

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can extend `RangeReplaceableCollection`, constrain its elements to `Equatable` and declare your method as mutating. If you want to return Bool in case the appends succeeds you can also make the result discardable. Your extension should look like this:

```
extension RangeReplaceableCollection where Element: Equatable {
    @discardableResult
    mutating func appendIfNotContains(_ element: Element) -> (appended: Bool, memberAfterAppend: Element) {
        if let index = firstIndex(of: element) {
            return (false, self[index])
        } else {
            append(element)
            return (true, element)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If `Element` is `Equatable`, you can just use `!contains(element)`

Comment: Oh wow, `@discardableResult`, `Equatable`, `Element`, I'm learning so much things in just one post! I've been thinking about how to make a result discardable so I don't need to use `_ = ...` but didn't know that such thing exists so I never look it up. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

I needed to prepend a unique element (removing it first if it already exists).

```
extension RangeReplaceableCollection where Element: Equatable
{
    mutating func prependUnique(_ element: Element) {
        if let index = firstIndex(of: element) {
            remove(at: index)
        }
        insert(element, at: startIndex)
    }
}
```

Comment: The difference between this approach and the accepted answer approach is that the accepted answer approach preserves the existing object index, while this approach uses the new object index instead. But my question is specifically about appending data. In my case, it's better if we preserve the existing object index instead. But thanks for your input.

Comment: Useful to track order of seen posts! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was filtering results and appending on clicking search button with api response but appending uniquely slow down the process as it has to check every index for unique, I basically made my local array empty or simply arr.removeAll().