# Swift Ordered Set

Tags: swift, set

Does Swift have an **ordered** set type? And if not, what are my options if I want to use one?

The standard library's `Set` is unordered, as is made clear in the documentation:

> Arrays are ordered collections of values. Sets are unordered collections of unique values. Dictionaries are unordered collections of key-value associations.

However, many data structures suitable for implementing ordered sets (and dictionaries) are known, in particular [balanced binary trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree) such as [Red-Black trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree).

As an example of this, c++'s stl has [ordered sets](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) and maps, and allows range queries on them using lower and upper bounds.

I know that a set's members can be sorted in to an array, but I am after a data structure with `O(log(n))` insertion, removal and query.

Comment: You will need to use an array to keep the elements order. You can use this answer to filter the duplicates from your array  https://stackoverflow.com/a/34712330/2303865 or make sure you only append to your array if it does not contain the element thats being appended https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46519004/can-somebody-give-a-snippet-of-append-if-not-exists-method-in-swift-array/46519116#46519116

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Swift does not have a native ordered set type. If you use `Foundation`, you can use `NSOrderedSet` in Swift. If not, you have the opportunity to write your own ordered set data structure.

**Update**: [Swift Package Manager includes an `OrderedSet` implementation](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/5d05348c6fd072ae7989ed8b55ac2b017486acf4/Sources/Basic/OrderedSet.swift) that may be useful. It wraps both an array and a set and manages access to get ordered set behavior.

**Update #2**: [Apple's Swift Collections repository](https://github.com/apple/swift-collections) contains an ordered set implementation.

Comment: `NSOrderedSet` is for any platform that includes Foundation. It's not just iOS.

Comment: Thank you, Tom – I'm reading around the subject currently. Yoda says, "Much to know, there is."

Comment: While you can use `NSOrderedSet` in swift it will always have a type of `Any` as it does not support generics

Comment: [A post here](https://airspeedvelocity.net/2015/07/22/a-persistent-tree-using-indirect-enums-in-swift/) implements a [persistent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_data_structure) [red black tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red–black_tree) in Swift. The post doesn't implement deletes as [shown here for Haskel](https://abhiroop.github.io/Haskell-Red-Black-Tree/). An apparently simpler approach is described [here](http://matt.might.net/articles/red-black-delete/) for [Racket](https://racket-lang.org) (a [Scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheme_(programming_language)) dialect).

Comment: Hey Tom – thanks for the diligent update! I just had a look at the `OrderedSet`. It has interesting semantics, but not what I'm looking for. It remembers the insertion order in to the `OrderedSet`, rather than maintaining the set's members with a total order as something like a red-black tree would.

Comment: @Benjohn I guess you are looking for something similar to `OrderedSet` where the elements are comparable and the data structure sorts the elements as they are inserted. Which is different from an orderedSet. I think some ppl have called this a SortedSet.  You can find one implementation of this the data structure
[here](https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-algorithm-club/blob/master/Sorted%20Set/SortedSet.swift). I definitely think one could build a great implementation of a SortedSet using `OrderedSet`.

Comment: Here is another implementation of [SortedSet](https://github.com/attaswift/BTree/blob/master/Sources/SortedSet.swift)

Comment: Hi again Tom – yes, the [SortedSet](https://github.com/attaswift/BTree/blob/master/Sources/SortedSet.swift) you point to is exactly the kind of thing I'm looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

On April 6th, 2021, a new package of Swift was released: Swift-Collection where three more data structures have been implemented. (`OrderedSet`, `OrderedDictionary`, `Deque`)

However, this package is in its pre-1.0 release state. As a result, it might not be stable.

[Swift blog: Release of Swift Collections](https://swift.org/blog/swift-collections/)

Answer (score 3):

At the time being there is no ordered set in Swift. Despite using `NSOrderedSet` on all Apple platforms, you can simply combine a `Set` with an `Array` to basically get the same effect. The `Set` is used to avoid duplicate entries, the `Array` is used to store the order. Before adding a new element to the `Array`, check if it is in the `Set` already. When removing an element from the `Array`, also remove it from the `Set`. To check if an element exists, ask the `Set`, it's faster. To retrieve an element by index, use the `Array`. You can change the order of elements in the `Array` (e.g. resort it) without having to touch the `Set` at all. To iterate over all elements, use the `Array` as that way the elements are iterated in order.

Comment: I'd say an ordered set is more like a set of (double-linked) list nodes so you'd get the benefits of O(1) lookups and can append/insert anywhere without constantly enumerating your array; or how would you suggest you handle insert before/after? Array inserts are O(n) worst case while inserting in a list would be O(1).

Comment: @Ron A double linked list has O(n) lookups, not O(1). It has only O(1) insertion and delete but only if the place for the operation is already known. All indexed operations would such be O(n) on such a linked list just for finding the place where to perform the operation, including `objectAt:`. One could also implement `NSArray` as a linked list but that would have the same disadvantages, which is why it isn't implemented that way.

Comment: Not when you make dictionary values (or keys, depends) list nodes. Sorry I forgot to mention that previously. LRU cache anyone?