# How to validate array value already exist or not

Tags: ios, arrays, swift

My task is picking `files` from `iCloud` and it's `url,title,etc.`,then appending into item `array`. After that, I am taking each values with help of `struct` and listing in `tableView`.

Here, one thing I need to understand, how to `validate` user picked files already exist or not into my array. If exist, I don't allow to append their file with `alert` message.

```
// Array Declaration
var items = [Item]()
var tableArray = [Item]() 

// Values appending into my array
items.append(Item(url: fileurl, title: filename, exten: fileextension, size: string))

// Tableview data load
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
    let item = tableArray[indexPath.row]

        if tableArray.count > 0 {
            cell.name_label_util.text = item.title
            cell.size_label_util.text = item.size
        }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: You need to show your Item declaration. You need to make your `Item` structure Equatable and check if your array contains it before appending

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46519116/2303865

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`contains(where:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2297359-contains) to check if the array contains the element by comparing the unique properties in the class.

```
if !items.contains(where: {$0.url == fileUrl}) {
    items.append(yourItem)
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Rakesha Shastri

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether `Item` is already existed or not, by adding a filter on existing `items` array. If result is `nil` then add the new item object.

**Note:** I am using `url` to check, it should be unique. Or replace it with unique key in `Item` modal.

```
if items.filter({ $0.url == fileurl }).first == nil {
    items.append(Item(url: fileurl, title: filename, exten: fileextension, size: string))
}
```

Alternatives:

```
if items.index(where: { $0.url == fileurl }) == nil {
    items.append(Item(url: fileurl, title: filename, exten: fileextension, size: string))
}
```

Comment: this will iterate the whole array even if it finds the element at the first array index. You should use contains(where:) instead of getting the first result of filter and checking if it is nil

Comment: Thanks, working nice. Btw, What is the difference between above two? @Ankit Jayaswal

Comment: I think filter and index-where do not follow linear search in swift, rather heap sort same as contains.

Comment: contains(where: yourPredicate) best one. Thank you @Leo Dabus and @ Ankit Jayaswal.

Comment: @pasteldev filter closure gives you array of matching results where you need to check for filtered array is empty or not, whereas index-where closure provide the index of matching result and you can directly check it with nil.